# How to put an ISO 8601 (or ISO 8601-like) pattern restriction on DateTime in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm trying to carry out XML validation using XSD (XML Schema Definition, XML v.1.0, encoding UTF-8) but it seems to be very challenging to come up with a valid pattern.

The pattern I would like to enforce is `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm: ss[.nnnnnnn] [+|-]hh: mm` with sample data looking like this: `2022-01-01 00:46:04.2147231+01:00`, `2022-01-01 00:46:04.2147231`, `2022-01-01 00:46:04.0000000` (as you can see, time zone offset is optional and there is no 'T' in between the date and time).

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1899590/18191762) works well but only with `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm: ss. nnnnnnn [+|-]hh: mm` DateTime format (i.e. you have to include time zone offset and the 'T').

Comment: *" it seems to be very challenging to come up with a valid pattern."* - what do you mean, "come up with"? XSD dates have a defined format: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime

Comment: @Tomalak Oh, so that 'T' separator is mandatory after all. I was under impression there is some "wiggle room".

Comment: No, the date format in XML - if you decide to adopt the XSD type system - is fixed. Of course you're free to pick any other format if you don't want to use XSD to validate your data types. :)

Comment: ...strictly speaking, you could still use XSD and a regex pattern restriction of `xs:string` that allows your custom format. It would work, but it would allow implausible dates that happen to fit the regex, eg. thinks like the 30th of February. Using `xs:date`/`xs:dateTime` would prevent this.

Comment: Yeah, I see. Much safer to stick with XSD precisely because of that (implausible date) problem. Thanks for advice :)

Comment: Saxon has an extension - the preprocess facet - that allows you to declare an item of type xs:dateTime, with a preprocessing XPath expression that converts the lexical-value as written to the lexical-value required by the dateTime type. This allows you to validate a format such as DD-MM-YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY and still get the benefit that 30th February is rejected.

Comment: Note that __none__ of the xs:dateime/xs:time really follow the ISO 8601. They only _partially_ compliant.